# Can you stop a HTML5 video pausing/stopping on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I have a HTML5 video banner at the top of my page. It has the `autoplay` and `loop` attributes added. When I begin to scroll down the page the video stops and never restarts when I scroll back upwards. I'd like the video to carry on playing no matter if the user scrolls or not.

There doesn't seem to be any attributes [listed in the W3C spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) that suggests a solution, so is there another way of disabling this functionality?

The HTML and CSS is very simple so I'm wondering if I need some JS to help along the way:

HTML:

```
<video preload="none" autoplay loop>
  <source src="/media/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) jQuery plugin as below:

```
$('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> it works fine for me,, if you want to change yiur viewport then change `fraction = 0.5;` in my code

```js
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"),
fraction = 0.5;
function checkScroll() {

    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

        var video = videos[i];

        var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
            b = y + h, //bottom
            visibleX, visibleY, visible;

            visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
            visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

            visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

            if (visible > fraction) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }

    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

```css
div {padding-top:300px; width:320px;}

video {
   
    padding-bottom:300px;    
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<video id="video1" preload="auto"  loop="loop">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">>
  bgvideo
</video>
    


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be disabled by using the attribute `data-keepplaying`.

```
<video preload="none" autoplay loop>
  <source src="/media/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This is only for fullpage.js, not anything to do with the HTML5 spec. However this was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: where is the data-keepplaying attribute?

Answer (score 0):

if using `fullpage.js`

```
<video autoplay muted loop data-keepplaying>
   <source src="myvide.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

works